# Regex to match comma-separated strings containing comma-formatted decimals

Tags: python, regex

I have comma-separated strings like this one:

```
"Assistência 24hs com Guincho s/limite de km, 2o. Guincho 100 km no mesmo evento, Pacote de Benefícios HDI, Táxi sem Franquia, Serviços Residenciais, 7 dias de Carro Reserva quando Terceiro (sem ar cond), 7 dias de Carro Reserva, Vidros com franquia de R$ 260,00."
```

I want to split the string by comma, but the problem is that there are numbers with a comma as the decimal separator in the string (for example: 260,00), for which I don't want a split to happen.

Comment: The commas you want to separate always have a space after them? If yes, you would use that to make the break. In fact, a simple .split(", ") would be enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could split by comma, followed by space:

```
>>> s.split(", ")
['Assist\xc3\xaancia 24hs com Guincho s/limite de km',
 '2o. Guincho 100 km no mesmo evento',
 'Pacote de Benef\xc3\xadcios HDI',
 'T\xc3\xa1xi sem Franquia',
 'Servi\xc3\xa7os Residenciais',
 '7 dias de Carro Reserva quando Terceiro (sem ar cond)',
 '7 dias de Carro Reserva',
 'Vidros com franquia de R$ 260,00.']
```

Note that this will remove both the comma and the following space from the resulting strings.

Comment: Whoa, I was so immersed in regular expressions that I'd forgotten to try the simple way. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

You're walking on thin ice here.  From your example,  it seems like using ", " as the field separator (comma-space) would work. Most would opt to quote the strings or use a different delimiter  (pipe, tab, \x1F, etc).

This seems very fragile to me,  and you could easily be broken further out in time. If you have any influence on what is being given to you,  have that conversation first.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no control over the source format. It's an HTML scraper I had to code for the lack of a proper API on the first place... fortunately it's just a fun little side project, nothing professional or anything. :)

Answer (score 0):

The following avoids the fragility that was pointed out by @dsz.

```
txt = '''Assistência 24hs com Guincho s/limite de km, 2o. Guincho 100 km no mesmo evento, Pacote de Benefícios HDI, Táxi sem 
Franquia, Serviços Residenciais, 7 dias de Carro Reserva quando Terceiro (sem ar cond), 7 dias de Carro
Reserva, Vidros com franquia de R$ 260,00.'''

import re
re.split("\,[^\d+\.\d+]",txt)
```

output:

```
['Assist\xc3\xaancia 24hs com Guincho s/limite de km',
 '2o. Guincho 100 km no mesmo evento',
 'Pacote de Benef\xc3\xadcios HDI',
 'T\xc3\xa1xi sem Franquia',
 'Servi\xc3\xa7os Residenciais',
 '7 dias de Carro Reserva quando Terceiro (sem ar cond)',
 '7 dias de Carro\nReserva',
 'Vidros com franquia de R$ 260,00.']
```